# How do you create a link to a specified section of your readme.md file?

Tags: markdown, readme

I am practicing readme files and I had a question about linking. Is there a way to link to a specific section of a readme? For example, I want to create a table of contents with links to the specific sections of my readme.md file.

```
# Title
## Sub Title
Brief description of project.

### Table of Content
* [Section 1](#section1)
* [Section 2](#section2)
* [Section 3](#section3)

# Section 1
some text

# Section 2
some text

# Section 3
some text
```

From my understanding I thought this would work but the links do not bring me to the sections, when I click them it does nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add an anchor to the section i.e

```
#<a name="section-1"></a> Section 1
```

then link it using

```
[Section 1](#section-1)
```

Comment: This is on FileMaker 18 Pro. I don't know if it used HTML? Either way this is strickly on the desktop, I'm not launching it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
### Table of Content
* [Section 1](#section-1)
* [Section 2](#section-2)
* [Section 3](#section-3)
```

will do the job. Note that anything but a normal character, such like a space for instance, has to be replaced by a -.